# How can I find (and delete) files by content in all subfolders in windows via the terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-10

I search file(s) for filename in folder and subfolders in *windows10* terminal:
`C:\Users\user1>dir settings.xml /s`.
I can find file(s) in folder and subfolder, but I don't know, how I can add search for text in file and delete them.
Other variant:
`C:\Users\user1>find "login" settings.xml`
There I can find for filename and text in file, but it not worked for subfolders.

Actually, I need both as alternative for *linux* comands:

```
grep -lrnw ~/.m2 -e '\u0000' | xargs rm
find ~/.m2/ -name resolver-status.properties -delete
```

My finish target: find and delete all files with name `resolver-status.properties` and contains `\u0000`.
How I can do this?
I tried to modify my commands for my targets. And I crashed.

Comment: What programming/scripting language do you want to use? If you want to use a shell, also state which shell. In any case, `find` and `grep` are just programs (not "linux commands"), for which you might even find an implementation that you can install on Windows systems.

Comment: Understand. I work with windows terminal only.

Comment: "windows terminal" is not enough. Powershell? `cmd.exe`? You can also run a Bash in a terminal on Windows...

Comment: cmd.exe
If you take me examples for Bash and Powershell - I can install and use this soft.